# IE Performance for large number of items

Tags: javascript, html, performance, internet-explorer

I'm comparing performance between a few frameworks (namely ReactJS and AngularJS) versus a "vanilla HTML + JS". During this I came across absolutely abysmal performance with Internet Explorer (I've tested in IE9 and IE11 and they both exhibit performance issues but differently).

The original code is an HTML file but I've moved it to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lordeagle/dc3aazpw/) for the sake of sharing it here. If you'd like, I can post it as a GitHub Gist, instead.

Anyways, goal is to render a table with 5,000 items in it (representing files and folders). On my test machine, IE11 takes around 30 seconds for the initial rendering while Chrome/Safari/Firefox are in the 1.5–3 second range. If I look at just how long it takes to generate the HTML string (so not even DOM manipulation), that alone is about 15 seconds on IE11 plus another 15 for actual rendering.

Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong? Make sure you change the `sampleSize` from 100 to 5,000 once you want to see the actual results:

```
var sampleSize = 100;
```

to

```
var sampleSize = 5000;
```

*Note:* here's what I've already done to improve performance:

- Changed the string concatenation of each row to using an array with a `.join('')` at the end which is a known performance issue with IE
- Only a single DOM access with `$(tblBody).html(nodes.join(''));` rather than append one row at a time

The above two enhancements brought the initial rendering from 36s down to 30s.

*Note 2:* the code is that **that** f*ed up since it's still faster than either my ReactJS- or AngularJS-based solutions. So the main question is: what in the world is IE doing?

Comment: Just thought I'd share.  IE10 on my machine had the following output:
Starting generation of 5000 data items 
 Time to generate data: 8ms 
 Time for generating folder strings for 1666 items: 7ms 
 Time for generating file strings for 3334 items: 14ms.  The rendering was quite slow in comparison though.  A few seconds at least.

Comment: Code or HTML relevant to the question should be pasted into the question.  External resources have a habit of disappearing or changing over time rendering the question kind of useless as a repository of knowledge.